# Python - Creating TestSuite with ordered TestCases

Tags: python, automation, test-suite

I came to Python from Java world. I found these TestNG-like tools: `py.test`, `nose2` and `unittest`. Played a little with all of them but I found some simple examples with `unittest` so I decided to stick to it. 
I automate only website's UI part for now with API automation on the horizon.

Does `unittest` runs added `Test Cases` in order I added those classes? If not how can I order them? 
Here's what I found:

```
import unittest
from SeleniumPythonRefactorTestCase import SearchText
from SeleniumPythonMultipleTests import HomePageTest

# get all tests from SearchText and HomePageTest class
search_text = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SearchText)
home_page_test = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(HomePageTest)

# create a test suite combining search_text and home_page_test
test_suite = unittest.TestSuite([home_page_test, search_text])

# run the suite
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(test_suite)
```

I have lots of different classes which consist some parts of logic so I can create different `Test Suites` using the same `Test Case` classes.

BTW, is `unittest` good for this job? Basically, I need this only for creating `Test Case` and `Test Suites`.

Thanks.

Comment: For functional UI tests, it's easier to play with robotframework + selenium. You shouls arrange unit tests with proper setups / teardowns such the test execution order does not matter. When fixing / adding a feature, you would like to run only specific tests and not the whole suite.

Comment: @glenfant, yes, I know about that framework but I found it a little bit complicated. I use Selene instead + webdriver manager.